# PHP: How to check which item in an array is closest to a given number?

Tags: php

I need to check which item in an array `array( 300, 600, 900, 1200 )` is closest to the number I have stored in a variable `$number`.

I've looked through the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) for either an approach or a function which will do this for me but my research has found nothing. Hoping someone can suggest something.

Comment: What should `450` return?

Comment: are your array values you are comparing to always evenly spaced like that? Because you could likely just do a simple `round($number / 300) * 300;`

Comment: php is a basic tool box. it providers a hammer, screwdriver, tape measure, etc... it is NOT a universal toolbox, and doesn't provide "random_functionality_only_I_need()". Use the basic tools and build the function yourself...

Comment: @mark the solution doesn't need to be hugley strict so perhaps just round up?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn the 300, 600, 900 is just an example. The array values will be different each time as will `$number`.

Comment: @MarcB I appreciate that. I was hoping this particular functionality was commonly sought after and something would be available already.

Comment: This is a statistical concept and It should has its own laws or formula to obtain it.

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: @Mark Yes. It's always in ASC order

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers in the array are always sorted in ascending order, you can loop through once checking distance as you go and soon as you start moving away from your number, return the last good number. Something like this:

```
<?php
$number = mt_rand(1, 1200);
$array = array(300, 600, 900, 1200);

function closest($number, $array){
    //infinite distance to start
    $dist = INF;
    //remember our last value
    $last = false;

    foreach($array as $v){
        //get our current distance
        $dist2 = abs($number - $v);

        //check if we are getting further than last number was
        if($dist2 > $dist){
            //return our last value
            return $last;
        }
        //set our new distance
        $dist = $dist2;
        //set our last value for next iteration
        $last = $v;
    }
    return $last;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($number);
var_dump(closest($number, $array));
```

Will output:

```
Input: int(522)
Output: int(600)
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NjcdP0

If the values are not sorted, you will need to loop over each value to get a distance and then find the smallest distance. Something like:

```
<?php
$number = mt_rand(1, 1200);
$array = array(300, 600, 900, 1200);

function closest($number, $array){
    //find distances to number
    $dist = array_map(
        function($val) use ($number) {
            return abs($number - $val);
        },
        $array);
    //flip array so distance is key
    $dist = array_flip($dist);
    //sort distance by key
    ksort($dist);

    //get key for shortest distance
    $key = array_values($dist)[0];

    return $array[$key];
}

echo "<pre>";
echo "Input: ";
var_dump($number);
echo "Output: ";
var_dump(closest($number, $array));
```

Outputs:

```
Input: int(677)
Output: int(600)
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/N5nv0v

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the *fastest* way to do this, but it can be written simply using `usort`. After you sort the array by absolute difference from the target number, the closest value will be the first one:

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) use ($number) {
    if ($a == $b) { return 0; }
    return abs($number - $a) > abs($number - $b) ? 1 : -1;
});

$closest = reset($your_array);
```

---

In PHP 7, the `usort` callback can be simplified with the combined comparison operator.

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) use ($number) {
    return abs($number - $a) <=> abs($number - $b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through and store both current result and difference, like this:

```
function closest_number(array $array, $number) {
    $result     = null;
    $difference = null;

    foreach ($array as $element) {    
        if ($difference === null || abs($element - $number) < $difference) {
            $difference = abs($element - $number);
            $result     = $element;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some magic code:

```
$arr = [300, 600, 900, 1200];
$number = 920;
$deltas = array_reduce(
    $arr, 
    function($t, $v) use ($number) { 
        $t[$v] = abs($v - $number); 
        return $t; 
    },
    []
);
asort($deltas);
echo array_keys($deltas)[0];
```